# Parabolic regularity for inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

We consider the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u + Lu =0 & \hbox{ in } \Omega\times[0,T] \\
u = f & \hbox{ on } \Omega\times \{0\} \\
u = g & \hbox{ on } \partial\Omega\times [0,T]
\end{cases}
$$
where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth bounded domain, and
$$
L = -\sum_{i,j=1}^n \partial_{x_i}( a_{ij}(x)\partial_{x_j}) + \sum_{k=1}^n b_k(x)\partial_{x_k} + c(x)
$$
where $a_{ij},b_k,c\in C^\infty(\overline\Omega)$ and
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\ge \lambda |\xi|^2
$$
for some $\lambda>0$, for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\in\Omega$.

What conditions must we impose on $f,g$ to have $u\in C^\infty(\Omega\times (0,T])$? A modification of arguments from Evans PDE gives that $f,g\in C^\infty$ suffices, for instance by taking $h$ on $\Omega\times[0,T]$ such that $L h=0$ and $h=g$ on $\partial\Omega\times[0,T]$ and using that
$$
\partial_t (u-h) + L(u-h) = -\partial_th \quad\hbox{ on }\Omega\times[0,T]
$$
and that $u-h$ has homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. Looking at the heat equation, I would expect $u\in C^\infty(\Omega\times(0,T])$ even when we only have $f,g\in L^1$, but is there a good way to prove this?

Comment: Do you mean $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t assume boundary data lie in $L^\infty$ in the context where this problem came up — the most I am able to assume is that $g\in L^{1+\varepsilon}$, or alternatively that $u,\nabla_xu\in L^{1+\varepsilon}_{t,x}$. If I had $u\in L^2$ then this would suggest using Nash moser theory, but my regularity seems a bit too weak for this.